# What counts as entering the zone of Grasping Shadows?

Tags: dnd-4e, spells, wizard

The Wizard Spell *Grasping Shadows* says in its description:

> **Effect:** The burst creates a zone or writhing shadows that last until the end of your next turn. Each creature that enters the zone takes psychic damage equal to your Intelligence modifier and is slowed until the end of its next turn. A creature can take this damage only once per turn.
>
> Source: *Arcane Power* 102, with [errata](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/updatesarchive).

Does "enters the zone" mean when the creature actually moves from a square not affected by this spell to a square affected by this spell, or does it mean whenever a creature moves into a square affected by this spell?

Answer (score 1):

Any movement (deliberate or forced) by a creature that results in crossing the outer boundary of the area from outside to inside is sufficient to suffer the consequences of the effect. At the moment of crossing the boundary, the damage and slowed condition apply, which may force the creature to stop moving if it has moved 2 or more squares already (see PHB p.277).

Moving from one square inside the area of effect to another inside does not count as entering the area because the creature was already inside the area. Teleporting to a square inside the area does count as entering, but teleporting across the area does not, as the creature would not actually occupy a square inside at any point.

When a creature is hit or missed by the spell's initial attack, it does not have to worry about the lingering effect, unless it leaves and then reenters the area.

This spell's effect was the subject of a [rules update](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/updatesarchive) which altered the trigger:

> Append the following sentence to the Effect entry. “A creature can take this damage only once per turn.”

Answer (score -4):

*"when the creature actually moves from a square not affected by this spell to a square affected by this spell"*

*"does it mean whenever a creature moves into a square affected by this spell?"*

You kinda said pretty much same thing there. What this means is that at anytime in a round if a character finds itself standing in a square within that area, either by voluntary or forced movement, even if they're not stopping and are just moving though, they're slowed and take damage. Though a character can only take damage from the area once per round.

Comment: This isn't accurate. It would be if the power said "any creature **in** the area", but instead it says "any creature **entering** the area". That comes with some major differences: among them, creatures that are _already in_ the area at the time of casting don't count as having "entered" it.

Comment: My mistake, I had read that paragraph and interpreted it differently.